# Merging DB Content From 2 DBs, Need To Avoid Non-Exact String Likenesses

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-like

Maybe I am day-dreaming but I am about to merge the contents of two large tables which represent two companies versions of the same data. I'd like to avoid duplicates (entries with the "title" field from DB 1 being *almost* the same as the "title" from DB 2. Are there any methods in php or mysql do do close string matches and return a relevance factor? Or any good php classes anyone knows of to check for likeness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [levenstein function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) in PHP.

In MySQL you will have to write [stored procedure for that](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/).